# How to get value of only one Element from an Xml file using XmlResourceParser on Android?

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

I'm using `XmlResourceParser` to extract values from elements. I used `msgBody= xmlResourceParser.nextText();` which returns value from both Message element i.e `i'm glad that you came to see me` and `Sorry wrong number`. I want to get only one from the top, how can i get that? My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Messages>
<Contact Name="Tomas" Number="079399877339">
<Message Date="30 Jan 2012" Time="23:36">i'm happy that you go to see her</Message>
<Message Date="31 Jan 2012" Time="11:34">this is a sample message</Message>
</Contact>
</Messages>
```

`.getText()` throws NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is wrong. To fix it:

1. Use SAXparser to parse XML.
2. Save all messages to a list (`List<Message>`)
3. Sort your message list by date, and grab the latest.

Comment: Thank you. I have worked with DOM and SAXparser before. 
Sorting by date is good idea and pick up the latest is good idea.